# Altering email sent to users when password is updated

Tags: wordpress

There is an email that is generated when the users' passwords are updated, that is sent from the admin to the user notifying them what the new password is. I've been looking for a way to change that but cannot find any mention of it in the docs.

the closes thing I found was [wp_password_change_notification](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_password_change_notification), but that sends email to the admin, not the other way around.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password you can declare this function in a theme or plugin ... wp uses if not defined to declare it..

Comment: This changes the password only, I'm trying to change the email template

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to change the content of the message sent after resetting a lost password then the [retrieve_password_message](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/) filter would work.

```
add_filter("retrieve_password_message", function ($message, $key) {
    // modify the message with your code here
    return $message;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Will this work for messages triggered by the admin changing/resetting password?